Options for leaning galvanized pole
I have a 4" diameter galvanized pole with concrete footing. I want to say 3 feet are in the ground because 9.5 feet are above ground. It is 11 inches from the corner of a concrete patio. The pole is straight but it is leaning about 5/8" per foot of height. It is leaning toward the patio and house. Frost depth here is effectively zero but we are prone to drought cycles that similarly mess with roads and fences.
I figure my options are:

attempting to surgically remove the pole and footing.
digging down to the top of the footing and cutting off the pole.
digging down and around the footing and trying to straighten the pole.

Do you see any other options? Are any of these options a certified disaster?


If the soil has been loosened, it might be surprisingly simple to remove the light string and rock the pole back and forth until it can be lifted out, complete with footing -- though it might take two brawny people to do it. Then a wider hole, with more concrete, could be use to support it.

How much are you willing to spend on a solution?  Is a guy wire out of the question?

Not so much a question of cost as it is of safety. I've knocked myself out on a clothesline as a kid. My kids are...a lot. And there's nothing higher up to anchor a guy wire to that's out of reach.
So I figure I move it to the actual patio or just cut it off. I wasn't planning on hanging more than party lights on it anyway, the sails were a disaster. Thanks so much!

for a temporary fix cut most of the way through and bend it vertical then weld it in its new orientation.  For a more permanent fix pull it out and auger a deeper wider footing.  the excavator that augers the footing may be able to pull it out.
Alternatively replace it with a pole that bolts to the slab.
I am assuming that the slab is well reinforced concrete.

Bolting to the slab is brilliant. Can hire somebody to dig the whole thing out or cut it off and then install it ON the slab. Yes.

The utility companies use an auger into the ground at an angle, probably 45º or steeper, and then a steel cable attached to their poles when they are being loaded at an angle like you have here.
This is what is happening here. The pole is loaded at a 90º angle so the weight of the aerial cable is pulling it out of plumb. Depending on the load it would have to be quite deep into the ground.
If you want to save the pole it will most likely need to be pulled back to plumb with a steel cable set at a 180º to the center of the angle of the two power cables.
If you don't want to save the pole then of course you can pursue any of the three options you outlined above. If it has a concrete pier around the pole in the ground then removing it completely will take a piece of equipment like a tractor, skid steer, or a tow truck.
The cheapest way to remove it may just be to dig down and cut the pole off with a reciprocating saw below ground level and fill the hole with topsoil.
Good luck with your project!s

The lights do not add any significant load. They're just hanging there and are not attached to a cable that is under tension. The damage was done by shade sails, which are gone, and also damaged the house.
But I take your point, there should have been some stabilization added at the point of install. Sort of like a corner fence post. Too late now, and the forces required to pull this thing back to plumb are scary...out of frame to the right is a swing set.
